# FCM Service worker is not working properly with nextjs in production (digitalOcean)

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

The FCM-Firebase Cloud Messageing service worker is not working with nextjs in production (digitalOcean), however, it's working fine locally and sending messages & notification properly

I have added a service worker to nextjs and it's working properly in development (localhost), but when I push the code to digitalocean the service worker through the below error:

> TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope
> ('https://${websiteurl}/public/') with script
> ('https://${websiteurl}/public/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP
> response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

And here is how it's implemented :-

1. After the normal firebase configuration, I've created the firebase-messaging-sw.js file in the public folder.
2. I've added the below code snippet to the _app.js file

```
useEffect(() => {
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker
                .register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
                .then(function (registration) {
                    console.log(registration.scope);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
    }, []);
```

That's how it's working with the local host, but the above error is thrown in the production knowing that I'm deploying the project to digitalOcean.